# Injecting dependencies into Angular services for testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do some test driven development of an angular service I'm writing using Jasmine. However, I seem to have stumbled at the first hurdle, and I cannot get my $resource dependency to resolve.

The error I get is
    Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- lookupService

My code is as follows

Module:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('common', ['ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate']);
})();
```

Service:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('common')
    .service('lookupService', lookupService);

lookupService.$inject = ['$resource', 'api'];

function lookupService($resource, api) {
    return {
        getLookup: getLookup
    };

    function getLookup() {
        return "something";
    }
}

})();
```

Test:

```
describe('Service tests',
function () {

    var lookupService, mockApi, $httpBackend;

    //mocks
    beforeEach(function () {
        mockApi = { getUri: jasmine.createSpy() };

        angular.mock.module('common',
            function ($provide) {
                $provide.value('api', mockApi);
            });
    });


    //injects
    beforeEach(function () {
        inject(function ($injector) {
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            lookupService = $injector.get('lookupService');
        });
    });



    //tests
    it('should be able to return something',
        inject(function () {
            expect(lookupService.getLookup()).toEqual("something");
        }));

});//Service tests
```

The angular-resource.js file is included in my runner file. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Karma? Can you check your karma.conf.js and see all your js files are included?

Comment: I'm actually just running them using standalone Jasmine. The module, service, test and all anguarjs files are included in the SpecRunner file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngResource must be a dependency:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('common', ['ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate', 'ngResource']);
})();
```